# Acrobat Javascript If Else to calculate on change in validate area

Tags: if-statement, field

I have a PDF form with 14 different calculations. When you input the value in one of the calculation boxes and then go to tab on to the next text field there is a delay as it does all of the calculations. What i am trying to do is write a JavaScript that will only do the calculation for the Total fields that are effected not all of the calculation on the form.
[field calculations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNvRq.png)
What I like to calculate Reg column (RegMON, RegTUE, RegWED, RegTHU, RegFRI, RegSAT, RegSUN, *RegTOTAL*)and total hours columns(DATHATTotal, HolTotal, OtherTotal, *RegTotal*, SickTotal, SrPayTotal, VACTotal, WBCompTotal) only on change in Reg column text fields including if changed from a number to blank. Here are the Total OT Hours columns(15Total, OT20Total, Trvl15Total, Trvl20Total).

New to JavaScript I have searched for examples on an "if statement that runs on text field change I did not find anything" any help would be greatly appreciated. I do have basic knowledge of Excel VBA but I very new to JavaScript.